# React-Router v4 separating Link and Route path elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

**(Updated for clarity)** I have the following structure for my App:

```
<Layout />
  /components/
    <Header /> 
    <Navigation />
    <Stage />
    <Footer />
  /pages/
    <Home />
    <About />
    <Contact />
```

My thinking is to have the `<Navigation>` element isolated, and imported into the parent `<Header>` (and later, Site Map).  All components are then staged into the parent `<Layout>`, which is fed into the `<div id="root">`

The content of my /pages/ Components are successfully called and rendered with the code below.  However this page content is rendered inside of my `<header>` element, breaking the page hierarchy.

My intention is to have the `<Switch>` device render the /pages/ Components within the `<Stage>` parent Component.

Any attempt to move the `<Switch>` element to the `<Stage>` component causes the whole app to not load/render.

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';


import Home from './../pages/Home';
import About from './../pages/About';
import Contact from './../pages/Contact';

export default class Navigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="navigation">

          <nav>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
          </nav>

{/*
  Below should be repositioned outside of <header>, in Stage component
*/}
          <div className="stage">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/about" component={About} />
              <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            </Switch>
          </div>

        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

My question is: How can I have the Router render the required /page/ Components inside my `<Stage>` component, when selected from the `<Navigation>` component.

Since all the **reacttraining.com** examples are single-page, I'm struggling to determine if I'm making a logic mistake in assuming how my app should be optimally constructed, or a programming error in recreating a relation between the two elements with react-router v4.

Comment: What happens if you close off the navigation <div> before opening the stage <div> rather than after?

Comment: It causes a breakage, as the Component must be wrapped in a single element.

Comment: So, closing off the navigation div before the stage div and then wrapping the two in a new single div should work.

Comment: Hi @Drum.  Seems my question needed clarifying to better describe my intentions.  Please see updates above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is to separate these two `div`s as you are wrapping `stage` inside the header. And as the Component needs to be rendered in a single element you need another `div` around the whole content:

```
export default class Navigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <div className="navigation">
            <nav>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
              <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
            </nav>
          </div>

          <div className="stage">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/about" component={About} />
              <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

**Update:**
Updating my answer:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => <h1>I'm a header</h1>;

const Navigation = () => (
  <nav>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
  </nav>
);

const Stage = () => (
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
  </div>
);

const Footer = () => <h6>Footer</h6>;

const Home = () => <h3>Home</h3>;
const About = () => <h3>About</h3>;
const Contact = () => <h3>Contact</h3>;

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Navigation />
      <Stage />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And here is the working version:
https://codesandbox.io/s/v21BD37NX

Comment: This would work as a solution, but perhaps I should have mentioned that I have `<Navigation />` feeding in to a `<Header />` parent component.  Therefore, the above suggestion would still render `<div class="stage">` within my `<header>`.  My objective is to completely isolate the `<Switch />` component to `/components/Stage.js` within my parent `<Layout />`

Comment: not sure I understand what you are trying to do, if you can draw out what you want achieve and explain step by step I might be able to help

Comment: Hi @knowbody, I updated my question for better clarity and much clearer definition of my intentions.  Happy to answer further questions.

Comment: @DarrenBarklie let me know if that's what you meant

Comment: Thanks so much @knowbody!  I don't know why I got so stuck on this.  Seeing it laid out this clearly helped me through my blockage.  I've since figured out isolating the Router to its own Navigation component and have everything working correctly.